# How to get values based on two dates columns from a different table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, table A has the Stock details and table B has the rates for certain product types valid for different periods.

```
create table tableA(
    Id int,
    StockId int, 
    AsOfDate date,
    Type_1_Bit bit,
    Type_2_Bit bit,
    Type_3_Bit bit,
    PurchaseDate date);
go

Create table TableB(
    Id int,
    BeginDate date,
    EndDate date,
    Rates decimal(8,5),
    Type_1_Bit bit,
    Type_2_Bit bit,
    Type_3_Bit bit);
go
```

I tried doing a left join with conditions but this logic gives me null rates. My resulting table should be like this--

```
select 
    a.Id,
    a.StockId,
    a.PurchaseDate,
    a.AsOfDate,
    b.Rates,
    b.Type_1_Bit,
    b.Type_2_Bit,
    b.Type_3_Bit
into #temp
from tableA a
left join TableB b
    on b.Type_1_Bit = a.Type_1_Bit
        and b.Type_2_Bit = a.Type_2_Bit
        and b.Type_3_Bit = a.Type_3_Bit
        and a.AsOfDate >= b.BeginDate
        and a.AsOfDate <= b.EndDate
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Without any knowledge of your model, no one can offer any useful analysis regarding the logic of your query. All we can say is that you use a left join so you should expect NULL rates for those rows in TableA that have no matching rows in TableB.

Comment: The rates are `NULL` either because the columns are `NULL` in the second table or there is no match.  It is that simple.  Your question doesn't have enough information to help beyond that.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I notice is you're doing:

```
and a.AsOfDate >= b.BeginDate
and a.AsOfDate <= b.EndDate
```

both `BeginDate` and `EndDate` need to be equal? If not, try using the `between` operator instead.

```
a.AsOfDate between b.BeginDate and b.EndDate
```

Comment: What you suggest is logically identical to what OP has written.

Comment: @Calu -- Guess what, this logic actually solved my problem. Thanks

Comment: BETWEEN is just syntactic sugar for the more verbose ">=' , "<=" usage. [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d1424551a1bf07ec7d00378a68ca46bd) to demonstrate.

Comment: @SMor you're right, still don't know how my comment solved the problem though. Anyway, thank you for helping me improve.